# Confused with scala type infer and type invariance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following simple code,

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) 
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val rdd: RDD[Product] = sc.parallelize(List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2))) //line 2
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))
val rdd2: RDD[Product] = rdd1 //compiling error
```

RDD[T] is invariance, so RDD[Person] is not subtype of RDD[Product], so there is compiling errors in the last line.

But I don't understand line 2

```
sc.parallelize(List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))
```

it is of type RDD[Person],  why can it be assigned to RDD[Product]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a very important part of type inference in Scala is expected type. The rules are spread out over https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html, but to explain this specific case:

In line 2,

1. `sc.parallelize(List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))` is typed with expected type `RDD[Product]`, so
2. `List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2))` is typed with expected type `List[Product]`, so
3. `Person("a", 1)` and `Person("b", 2)` are typed with expected type `Product` and this succeeds because `Person` is a subtype of `Product`.
4. The compiler inserts type parameters

   ```
    sc.parallelize[Product](List[Product](Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))
   ```

Note that `RDD[Person]` never even appears in this process. I.e.

> ```
> sc.parallelize(List(Person("a", 1), Person("b", 2)))
> ```
>
> it is of type RDD[Person]

isn't correct; it can be of this type, but in line 2 it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Taken From Here: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Product.html

> Base trait for all products, which in the standard library include at
>   least scala.Product1 through scala.Product22 and therefore also their
>   subclasses scala.Tuple1 through scala.Tuple22. In addition, all case
>   classes implement Product with synthetically generated methods.

I was able to run your code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkSample {

  object SparkSessionConf {
    val LOCAL_MASTER = "local[*]"
  }

  def initializeSpark(master: String, appName: String): SparkSession = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    SparkSession.builder
      .master(master)
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = initializeSpark(SparkSessionConf.LOCAL_MASTER, "SparkTry")

    val rdd: RDD[Product] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List(Person("ss", 10), Person("ss", 20)))
    val rdd1: RDD[Product] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List(Person("ss", 10), Person("ss", 20)))

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You have missed the critical point `val rdd2: RDD[Product] = rdd1` //compiling error

Comment: If you look carefully what I am doing that leads to the compiling error. you will also hit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://skipoleschris.blogspot.com/2011/06/invariance-covariance-and.html) is detailed description about invariance with example and explained why you can not cast Person class to Product trait even though it seems natural that we should be able to do so.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. It asks why it appears that you _can_ cast in this case.